# Internet Explorer 10 Hanging up when adding TypeGeometry Three.js

Tags: three.js, internet-explorer-10

I have created a project that takes in a large amount of vertices,normals. It renders without issue with the webgl renderer. but with the canvas renderer it just hangs for ever after adding the mesh to the scene. any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CanvasRenderer` can handle up to ~3,000 triangles. `SoftwareRenderer` however, can handle more, but it needs some work on shading code.

Comment: Will the SoftwareRenderer work with non-webgl browsers?

Comment: Also i dont see the SoftwareRenderer in the docs or in the source. I am not to concerned with shading at this moment.

Comment: Ok got it to load the vertices still a little slow but it does show up. Now i cannot figure out how to get rid of the black background. i tried using renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1); but it did not work

Comment: Hmmm, could you share the project files?

Comment: figured it out. just needed this renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0); instead. You have been great.